# Kibana: Why i got an error of script value : aggregation_execution_exception?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I got this error:

> An error occurred when loading data. Request error:
> aggregation_execution_exception, Unsupported script value[0.0],
> expected a number, date, or boolean in Painless script.

Here is my script field **add**:

```
def test = doc['log_data_numerical'];
return test;
```

I take a number and it returns a number in time format.

Here is my second log for testing the problem: [second log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITfSV.png) and my first log that doesn't work and is created in live: [first log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icjec.png).

The problem is when I try to do a Pie with some values (**log_data_info**1 -> weather & **log_data_info2** -> car_mode) the first time i tried to do that with the first log in live but i got that : [error pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycw14.png).

So the problem is **log_data_numerical** is a string for kibana and not a number but I don't understand why because it takes just a number (0.0, 0, or some other values like 7.9293839).

I tried to do the same but with a log that I create from the first log the [second log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITfSV.png) and it's work: [good pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p2UI.png) but i don't know why it's take the same values than the first log and in my script field i can change :

```
def test = doc['log_data_numerical'].value;
return test;
```

And i can save but normally that would not be possible since there are only numbers.

Edit: here is the type of

- first log [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJls7.png)
- second log [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8d9E.png)

So please if someone knows why my **log_data_numerical** in my live stream log isn't considered as a number type and how to fix it I would be very grateful!

Comment: Have you tried `doc['log_data_numerical'].value` ? (see `.value` at the end)

Comment: Yes i tried it but it's the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found the problem.
It was from the logstash, i force it to being a number type and not a string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).